# Receiving Intent from a non-Activity class

Tags: android, android-context

Is it possible to handle Intent `ACTION_SEND` outside of an Activity class?

I was to receive Intent that doesn't open an Activity, where the class creates a Notification to show that the Intent is being processed as opposed to opening the app.

I'm sure this could be achieved with a Service that's always running, but I only want a Service to run immediately prior to creating the Notification, above.  (In other words, processing of the `ACTION_SEND` Intent needs to be transparent other than presenting the Notification.)

The task, as best I can figure, is establishing a Context in a non-Activity class to feed to `getSystemService()`, though I'm at a loss how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to avoid UI then in fact, extending `Activity` does not mean you have to show any. So if you do not need to open any vUI in your class, then once your `onCreate()` is called just init it as usual by caling `super.onCreate(bundle)`, then do what you want to do there, but do not call any `setContentView()`. Then at the end of your `onCreate()` jump to another activity or just kill that one with `finish()`.